# XPages dblookup issue

Tags: xpages

I have an item description from a third party lookup that contains an inch symbol. The DbLookup on Xpages does not seem to work with an inches symbol as the key. Example code:

```
var itemdesc = "BOLT F.T.(1/2" X 1-1/2")";

server = @Name("[CN]", @Subset(@DbName(), 1));

var db = new Array(server,databasename);

var itemcode = @DbLookup(db, view, itemdesc, 2,"[FAILSILENT]");
```

DbLookup returns undefined. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't use " in a lookup filter them out before or replace them with some other char

Comment: I think you're right, I have tried all other special characters and DbLookup works on them except for quotation marks. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try var itemdesc = "BOLT F.T.(1/2\" X 1-1/2\")";

Comment: As an aside, don't use @dblookup, it is slow. Just use SSJS and getalldocumentsbykey

Comment: Yes i have tried adding "\" before the inches symbol but still does not work.  Okay, I will try using SSJS and getalldocumentsbykey.

Comment: Thank you @Howard. I got it working already, i used SSJS and getdocumentsbykey.